# How to transfer data to android?

Tags: data-transfer

I just took a phone android, before I had an iphone.
I want to tune all my data (photos, videos and contacts) on my new phone.
How can I do? I do not know any solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching​ from IPhone to Android is really easy. You'll need Google drive installed on your iPhone and set your Google account.

Further explanations can be found [here](https://www.android.com/switch/)

If your android device is a Samsung, you'll need [Smart Switch app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.easyMover).

To get started, you'll first need to install  Samsung Smart Switch Mobile app from the Play Store on your Samsung device.

After launching the app, select iCloud from the list of options. The service works by using your iCloud device backup, and transferring your information to the Samsung device.

You may not feel comfortable with giving Samsung your Apple credentials. For this scenario,  Samsung has created a desktop tool to transfer your information. The tool can be found [here](http://www.samsung.com/smartswitch).
Just follow the steps on screen.